# Bash Loop Variable from print

Tags: bash

Update - kind of got it working with the following but getting

Cannot find device "eth0
eth1"

so its trying to add both as a variable and not a single line

```
#!/bin/bash

gateway=$(ip route | awk '/default / {print $3}'y)
broadcast=$(ip route | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')
interface=$(basename -a /sys/class/net/* | awk '/eth/{print $1}')

for x in $interface
do
ip rule add from "$broadcast" table vrack
ip route add "$broadcast" dev "$interface" table vrack
ip route add default via "$gateway" dev "$interface" table vrack
ip route add "$broadcast" dev "$interface" table vrack

done

systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: Arrays are your friend.

Comment: it looks like you could reduce duplication and also eliminate harcoding the number of interfaces by strategic use of arrays and loops.

Comment: `interfaces=( /sys/class/net/* ); interfaces=( "${interfaces[@]##*/}" )` for example will give you an array called `interfaces` with values `"${interfaces[0]}"` through `"${interfaces[5]}"` (assuming that's the number of items you actually have).

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for variables that have internal meaning to the shell itself or OS-defined tools. Use lowercase names for your own variables to avoid unintentional conflicts.

Comment: (`for interface in "${interfaces[@]}"; do` or even just `for interface in /sys/class/net/*; do interface=${interface##*/}; ip route add "$broadcast" dev "$interface" table vrack; ip route add default via "$gateway" dev "$interface" table vrack; done` as an extended example -- don't need an array when you can loop directly over the glob results)

Comment: Note that to be on-topic here, questions need to be about narrow, specific problems. While I closed it as duplicative of three separate smaller problems with answers that combine to address your larger issue, it also could have been closed as "too broad" since it isn't focused on a specific issue and is instead an open-ended "help me refactor this code" request.

Comment: ... `ip route | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}'` could be wrong!  Try this *pure [tag:bash]*: `while read iface dest gate _{,,,} mask _;do case $dest$mask in 0000000000000000 ) defIface=$iface defRoute=$gate;;* ) printf -v iface_$iface %s/%s $dest $mask ;;esac;done < /proc/net/route ;declare -n defGate=iface_${defIface};printf '%s: %d.%d.%d.%d / %d.%d.%d.%d via %d.%d.%d.%d\n' $defIface 0x${defGate:6:2} 0x${defGate:4:2} 0x${defGate:2:2} 0x${defGate::2} 0x${defGate: -2} 0x${defGate: -4:2} 0x${defGate: -6:2} 0x${defGate: -8:2} 0x${defRoute:6:2} 0x${defRoute:4:2} 0x${defRoute:2:2} 0x${defRoute::2}`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hard to say, this question is wide! Maybe a dup of [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/1765658)

Comment: (btw, in a real-world case I'd proabably want to add some logic to the loop to use `continue` to skip things that _aren't_ valid names corresponding with interfaces you want to handle in this way; not sure this logic is correct for `lo`, for example, so `[[ $interface = lo* ]] && continue` might be called for -- but this all depends very much on details that haven't been added into evidence here)

Comment: I kind of got it going - but its not running each as a variable its adding all the lines in at once.

Comment: @ChrisMurrell, since there are no answers added (just comments, which are fair game to invalidate via edits) it's an option open to you to [edit] this into a completely different question, if you want to modify it to show your new code and the new problem. Anyone with enough reputation in the bash tag can singlehandedly reopen it if we agree it's a good question after you've done so.

Comment: Okay, the big problem now is that you didn't actually follow the advice to make an array for interfaces. Your `interface=$(...)` is making `interface` one big string, not an array at all. See [BashFAQ #5](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) for an introduction to arrays.

Comment: Think about `for interface in /sys/class/net/*; do interface=${interface##*/}; [[ interface = eth* ]] || continue; ...; done` for your loop.

Comment: (please _ask questions_ about suggestions you don't understand or that look like they wouldn't work, instead of just ignoring them!)

Comment: @Charles Duffy
Bit confused on what the actual command would be

Comment: I thought I gave you an actual command a few comments up; all you need to do is replace the `...` with the content of your loop (like `ip route add "$broadcast" dev "$interface" table vrack`).

Comment: Or if you really do want an array, `readarray -t interfaces < <(basename -a /sys/class/net/* | awk '/eth/{print $1}')`, but I really hate to advise that command -- it's needlessly inefficient to fork off several subprocesses (a subshell, a copy of the `basename` executable, and a copy of the `awk` executable) for something the shell could do itself built-in with no forking at all.

Comment: (and once you've built an array that way, it's `for interface in "${interfaces[@]}"; do` to iterate over it, as the FAQ entry linked above states)

Comment: do you mean like this? it doesnt work? im getting even more confused

interface=$(basename -a /sys/class/net/* | interface=${interface##*/}; [[ interface = eth* ]] || continue;)

Comment: When I said `for interface in /sys/class/net/*; do interface=${interface##*/}; [[ interface = eth* ]] || continue; ...; done`, I meant **exactly** that. No `interfaces=` anything, no `$()` anything; when you go that route, you don't _need_ an interfaces array at all.

Comment: where would i add "readarray -t interfaces < <(basename -a /sys/class/net/* | awk '/eth/{print $1}')"

Comment: sorry getting more and more lost

Comment: The `readarray` command is an equivalent to `interfaces=$(...)` that creates `interfaces` as an array instead of a string. (So it's an alternative to the `for interface in /sys/class/net/*` approach -- use one or the other, not both).

Comment: not getting any errors but doesnt seem to be adding the routes when doing that

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/25cae8331b2b624fd789eb5de60539e3 showing complete scripts for two different approaches I've been suggesting.

Comment: I'd suggest running `bash -x yourscript` to enable trace logging so you can see what it's actually doing during execution.

Comment: Thanks - that does it but only finds the first network interface eth0 not eth1

Comment: Assuming you're using the array approach, did you maybe use `$interfaces` instead of `"${interfaces[@]}"`? That would make it only do the first.

Comment: Thank you - doesnt seem to be running "ip route add "$broadcast" dev "$interface" table vrack" even after its been flushed - works when i manually add the command

Comment: its still trying to add both "ip route add default dev eth0 eth1 table vrack"

Comment: this is the debug https://pastecode.io/s/mq3yfcqv

Comment: code so far https://pastecode.io/s/nkdib49c

Comment: @charles-duffy - ps thank you so much for your help so far.
i have fixed the broadcast - getting the multiple interfaces still "ip route add 0.0.0.0/23 dev eth0 eth1 table vrack"

Comment: fixed it - https://pastecode.io/s/mq3yfcqv

Thank you so much for your help. still a bit messy but much better than it was

Comment: (Pardon the long delay -- I was afk for lunch; taking a look now)

Comment: ...consider my grumbling about `for x in $interfaces` instead of using a real array to be repeated. [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) touches on the problems somewhat, as does [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: (the bug in https://pastecode.io/s/nkdib49c is that you used `readarray`, but then you used `for x in $interfaces` and not `for x in "${interfaces[@]}"`; those two changes need to be both made together; when you do one and not the other they don't work)

Comment: (since you got it working, I assume you either added `| head -n 1` to the pipeline setting `gateway`, or did some equivalent?)